# Do HTML File Uploads Work On A BlackBerry Browser?

Tags: php, html, blackberry, file-upload

Does the file select control -- `<input type='file' />` -- work in the BlackBerry browser?

I set up a simple HTML form to upload a file - works fine on my desktop browser, but the BlackBerry browser seems to ignore the file input and instead sends the file name as a post field.

This is what I have experienced on a Curve 8520. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's the baseline code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data"  action="action.php"  >

<input type='file' name='import'  /> Select a file 

<input type='submit' name='upload' >

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes blackberry supports form element of type 'File'. 'Name' attribute for form element is required. These three attributes are accepted - accept(optional), name (required), value (optional). `<input type ='file'>` - ***When specified, the browser renders a button control that opens a dialog box in which users can browse for a file. The browser displays the file name of the selected file in the form, and includes the file when the user submits the form.*** Also this option is available for ***version 4.6 or later***

You can review this for more reference - http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18027/HTML_input_types_1247751_11.jsp